# Primefaces LazyDataModel sortField and sortOrder not set

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable, lazy-loading

I've created simple implementation of Primefaces' `LazyDataModel`. Now paginator works right, but when I set `sortBy="..."` attribute on some Datatable's column and try to sort table by clicking the column header on my JSF page, in `LazyDataModel#load` method I'm still getting `sortField` set to `null` and `sortOrder` set to `ASCENDING`. The ajax request is sent, containing sort field and order, however, this data are not passed to the load() method.

My backing bean providing the data model to JSF is `@Named @ViewScoped`, I'm using Wildfly 8 (JSF 2.2.5), Primefaces 4. Any tips?

```
    @Override
public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    System.out.println("FIELD: " + sortField + ", ORDER: " + sortOrder);
.......



<p:dataTable value="#{logsBacking.appLogModel}"
paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="10"
var="appLog" lazy="true" rowKey="#{appLog.id}">
    <p:column headerText="test" sortBy="id}">
        <h:outputText value="id" />
    </p:column>
............
```

Comment: Have you tried with `sortBy="#{appLog.id}"` ?

Comment: yes, however the value is never passed to sortField of load() method. I've also tried to add some filters and there are also not passed. Only passed parameters are int first and int pageSize

Comment: Just a guess: use `sortBy="#{appLog.id}"` in `<p:dataTable>` and remove it from `<p:column>`

Comment: yes, it works well, however I need to enable sorting on selected columns. Cannot this be some problem with JSF state saving/view scope or Primefaces/Mojarra bug?

Answer (score 2):

try to override the other load(), getRowKey() and getRowData() too.

this is mine, and it is working:

```
public class EntityDataModel<T extends AbstractEntity> extends LazyDataModel<T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected final Class<T> entityClass;
    protected final EntityConverter converter;
    protected final PersistenceService service;

    public EntityDataModel(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        super();
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.converter = new EntityConverter();
        try
        {
            this.service = PersistenceService.lookup();
        }
        catch(NamingException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        setPageSize(1);

        setRowCount(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filterMap)
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> resultList = service.queryAll(entityClass, first, pageSize, filterMap, multiSortMeta);

            setRowCount(service.count(entityClass, filterMap).intValue());

            return resultList;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filterMap)
    {
        return load(first, pageSize, Lists.newArrayList(new SortMeta(null, sortField, sortOrder, null)), filterMap);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(T entity)
    {
        return converter.getAsString(null, null, entity);
    }

    @Override
    public T getRowData(String rowKey)
    {
        return (T) converter.getAsObject(null, null, rowKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex)
    {
        super.setRowIndex(getPageSize() == 0 ? -1 : rowIndex);
    }
}
```

---

@PhilHDN

The `PersistenceService.queryAll()` makes use of many internal objects to create a dynamic query with dynamic order.

Here is a tailored version:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public <T> List<T> queryAll(Class<T> entityClass, int first, int max, Map<String, ?> filter, List<SortMeta> sortList)
{
    return queryAll(entityClass, first, max, createRestriction(filter), createSort(sortList));
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public <T> List<T> queryAll(Class<T> entityClass, int first, int max, Restriction<? super T> restriction, Sort<? super T> sort)
{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = builder.createQuery(entityClass);

    Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);

    cq.select(root).distinct(true);

    if(restriction != null)
    {
        cq.where(restriction.apply(builder, root));
    }

    if(sort != null)
    {
        cq.orderBy(sort.apply(builder, root));
    }

    TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery(cq);

    if(first > -1)
    {
        query.setFirstResult(first);
    }
    if(max > -1)
    {
        query.setMaxResults(max);
    }

    return query.getResultList();
}

private <T> Sort<T> createSort(List<SortMeta> sortList)
{
    return (builder, root) ->
    {
        List<Order> ret = new LinkedList<>();

        if(sortList != null)
        {
            for(SortMeta sortMeta : sortList)
            {
                String field = sortMeta.getSortField();
                SortOrder sortOrder = sortMeta.getSortOrder();

                if(field == null || field.isEmpty())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Expression<?> expr = root.get(field);

                if(sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING)
                {
                    ret.add(builder.asc(expr));
                }
                else if(sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING)
                {
                    ret.add(builder.desc(expr));
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    };
}

public interface Sort<T> extends BiFunction<CriteriaBuilder, Root<? extends T>, List<Order>>
{
    // empty
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you share your `queryAll` method? I would like to know how to use `List<SortMeta>` in your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`p:dataTable` **MUST** be inside a `h:form` so that filters work properly.